# Display file content line by line

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Is it possible to read file content in and displaying it line by line in browser under a 
 in ruby on rails. It should appear as video is being played.

Comment: Sure, this is possible. Go ahead and give it a shot.

Comment: Google, your best friend: https://www.google.com/search?q=ruby+read+file&oq=ruby+read+file&aqs=chrome.0.57j5j0l2j60l2.2230&sugexp=chrome,mod=3&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: can you give explanation .... are you looking to display each line like a slide show being played in a specific div..as ads are displayed in a webpage...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did u mean show raw file content in html page like this https://raw.github.com/intridea/oauth2/master/lib/oauth2.rb

and each line is wraped by hyperlink, if u say so , it's possible

use js solution

```
   (function($) {
$.fn.typewriter = function() {
    this.each(function() {
        var $ele = $(this), str = $ele.html(), progress = 0;
        $ele.html('');
        var timer = setInterval(function() {
            var current = str.substr(progress, 1);
            if (current == '<') {
                progress = str.indexOf('>', progress) + 1;
            } else {
                progress++;
            }
            $ele.html(str.substring(0, progress) + (progress & 1 ? '_' : ''));
            if (progress >= str.length) {
                clearInterval(timer);
            }
        }, 75);
    });
    return this;
};
  })(jQuery);
```

at your index.html.erb

```
  <body>
     <div id="code" style='display:none'>
       <%= File.open("#{full_path}").readlines.join("<br/>") %>
     </div>
     <script> $('#code'). typewriter() </script>
  </body>
```

you can put your css on code element

Comment: No  I want to display all file content in running mode.. It should display content character by character... Firstly 1st character... then first and second character.. then frst second and third... So it ll appear as we are watching a video.. in which somebody is writing content to a file.

Comment: I found an intresting project, maybe is that u want. http://love.hackerzhou.me/,  u can achieve this to use js .

Comment: Yes. This is what i want. Can u tell me how can i implement it?

Comment: They have used typewriter(); Is it built method of JavaScript?